# JQuery - Checking for gridview pager table row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have implemented a datasource bound gridview on my aspx page and have added the following jquery to implement several changes when the user hovers over a row. The problem is the jquery also comes into play when you hover over the bottom pager row e.g to change the grid page etc. I had it working with following besides in the case when there isn't a pager row on screen. I've also tried looking for the 'gridheader' class, counting rows etc but none of them seem to do the job.

```
function PageLoaddCallback(sender, args) {
    $("*[id$='gridResults'] tr:not(tr:last-child)").unbind();
    $("*[id$='gridResults'] tr:not(tr:last-child)").filter(function () {
        return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
    }).hover(
            function () {
                var totalRows = $("#<%=gridResults.ClientID %> tr").length;
                m_bgcolour = $(this).css("background-color");
                var _img = $(this).find("*[id$='hdnField']").val();
                var _name = $(this).find("*[id$='hdnName']").val();
                if ((_img == null) || (_img == "")) {
                    var src = "../../Images/Resources/NoSignature.jpg";
                    _name = "Unknown";
                }
                else {
                    var src = "GetImage.axd?id=" + _img;
                }

                $("#largeImg").attr("src", src);
                $(this).css({ background: "#c4ffc4" });
                $("#lbl").html(_name);
            },
            function () {
                var src = "../../Images/Resources/sample.jpg";
                $("#largeImg").attr("src", src);
                $(this).css({ background: m_bgcolour });
                $("#lbl").html("Sample");
            }
            );

}
```

});

Any help would would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put a special CssClass on the pager rows like so:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <PagerStyle cssClass="pagerRow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

You should then be able to use that to filter out the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.. couldn't get your suggestion to work so added a css class to the data rows and changed selector to find the class:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-CssClass="dataRow">

$("*[id$='gridResults']").find(".dataRow")
```